# I'm trying to call multiple images (frames) and applying a filter on all of them

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

So I got the frames of an image and now i need to turn them all black without the opencv black and white filter, but I can use opencv for the rest. My issue is that `img_data = image.getdata()` is not working , idk.

```py
def bw():
    #images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob("C:/PythonProjects/*frame.jpg")]
    img_dir = "C:/PythonProjects"  # Directory of all images
    data_path = os.path.join(img_dir, '*frame.jpg')  #Filter becouse I only want some type of images
    files = glob.glob(data_path)
    data = []
    for j in files:
        img = cv2.imread(j)
        data.append(img)         #Save the images into a list

    count = 0
    for i in range(0, 128):      #128 are the numbers of images I want to work with
        image = img[i]               #Select image by image from the list
        img_data = image.getdata()    #Get the data

        # Run the image
        lst = []
        for i in img_data:
            lst.append(i[0] * 0.2125 + i[1] * 0.7169 + i[2] * 0.0689)     #Black and White algorithm
                                                                          #Using the pixels then saving them to a List
        #New Image
        new_image = Image.new("L", image.size)
        new_image.putdata(lst)                            #Put the data from the list to the new image

        #Save the image
        cv2.imwrite("bwframe%d.jpg" % count, new_image)
        count += 1
```

Comment: What error do you get?  Are you sure you actually have a valid frame? Check the shape or view it to be sure. OpenCV and PIL use different formats. Do you convert properly?

Comment: Yeah the frame is valid im almost sure, the error is : img_data = image.getdata()    #Get the data
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'getdata'

Comment: why do you call `.getdata()`?

Comment: to get the information from the image, size pixels etc.

Comment: You shouldn't be using OpenCV `cv2.imread()` and `cv2.imwrite()` as well as PIL `Image.new()`, `putdata()` and `getdata`. Use one or the other else you'll confuse yourself. You also shouldn't be using `for` loops or lists for image processing - try to use Numpy or optimised OpenCV or PIL methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a small typo: You are accessing `img` instead of `data`. Change like this:

```
....
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, 128):      #128 are the numbers of images I want to work with
    image_data = data[i]         #get the image data 
....
```

Edit: Changed data access.

Comment: I tried that change and this error appeared : img_data = image.getdata()    #Get the data
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'getdata'

Comment: Oh you are right then just don't use get_data() :) image_data = data[i] because you store the image data (numpy arrays) instead of an object. Gonna edit the answer

Comment: Now the error passed to this line: new_image = Image.new("L", img_data.size),this error:("Size must be a tuple")

Comment: okay now i called an image just to get the size of it to use it and it worked, and changed a little of the code, now the error is in the final line, here is the line: ```py cv2.imwrite("bwframe%d.jpg" % i, new_image)``` and the error is :  ```    cv2.imwrite("bwframe%d.jpg" % i, new_image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imwrite'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img' ```

Comment: you are **still** mixing up opencv and PIL. stop that. mixing them up is the cause of all your issues.